# Flex TextArea Strings and prohibited characters i.e. <meta charset="utf-8">

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, character

I'm trying to set the text of a TextArea with some text containing forbidden characters. I'm trying to set the text as `<meta charset="utf-8">` and there is of course a problem with the "'s. I think it's something like this  `<meta charset=&#0034utf-8&#0034;>`, but obviously this doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding your question ... does `<mx:TextArea id='aTextArea' text='<meta charset="utf-8">' />` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure if you mean you are having trouble with setting text to a textarea when the text contains single quote character. You need to escape the quote or you could enclose the string in double quotes.

Take a look at
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_03.html#445094

Comment: Thanks :) I knew it was something simple.